# Cannot log on to Careers 2.0

Tags: support

when I try to apply for a job it is asking me to log in. but myopenid is greyed out. But I am logged in under myopenid. So where does that leave me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, MyOpenID is dead - you may have logged in using it the last time you logged in, but that was *many months ago now*; since then, [the service has become unavailable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac) with the former operators having no plans to resume service.

**So before you do *anything* else, [add another login method to your SO account!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)** If you don't, you'll find yourself locked out if you should lose your current session.

I'm serious. Stop reading *right now* and go do that.

GO!

Ok, once you're able to log into SO again from a fresh browser session, the answer to your Careers question becomes easy: just log in using whatever new service you added to your SO account. If you somehow end up with *two* Careers accounts, you can contact [the support team](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) for assistance in merging them.